# 1/4 of my Christmas palm dead, do I cut or leave alone?

Tags: plant-health

One forth of Christmas palm seems dead.  Other parts of cluster seem to be doing fine but I don't know if I should cut the dead part off or hope it will come back.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have palm weevils in your area?

The tree is dead as said by GardenGems. Cut the trunk to pieces, and if you see holes, there might be some beetle larvae. In that case, a better solution is to burn the trunk, to avoid further dispersion of the pest.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer;

You should remove that trunk.  Once a palm has lost it's growing point it is dead.  Many plants if cut back they will sprout two new stems, but that is not true of palms.  A palm has one growing point that is it. That trunk will not grow anymore and should be removed.  One the reason to remove it is, because left the way it is it might start to rot.  The rot might move down to the roots and spread to the rest of the plant.

Comment: I have even seen 5 maple trees grow out of a single stump.